# How to print a single document in pdf via Word 2007 (mail merge)

Tags: vba, pdf, printing, ms-word, mailmerge

I have got an interesting question and I couldn't find an answer somewhere. 
I need to print around 2000 letters and of course I will do it with Mail Merge. Problem: I need every single one printed out in pdf-format. I found out that I have to use VBA macros in Word to get single letters (and not to get the whole bulk of letters in just one document) and this already works. But I couldn't find out how to automatically transfer them into pdf.

Does anyone has an idea and can help me? I appreciate your help.

What I got so far (to make single documents with mail merge):

```
    Sub EinzelDatei() 

    Dim actpath As String, Dateiname As String 
    Dim fs As Object 
    Dim LetzterRec As Long 


    Const path As String = "D:\Test\" 

    On Error GoTo 0 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Application.Visible = False 

    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord 
    LetzterRec = Word.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord 

    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord 

    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge 
        .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord 
        Do 
            If .DataSource.ActiveRecord > 0 Then 
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument 
                .SuppressBlankLines = True 

               With .DataSource 

                    actpath = path & "\"          'Der aktuelle Pfad wird zusammengesetzt 

                    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
                    If fs.folderexists(actpath) = False Then MkDir (actpath) 'Wenn der Pfad         noch nicht existiert wird er jetzt erstellt 


                    .FirstRecord = .ActiveRecord 
                    .LastRecord = .ActiveRecord 

                Dateiname = actpath & _ 
                    .DataFields("No").Value & "-" & _ 
                    .DataFields("Surname").Value & "," & _ 
                    .DataFields("First_Name").Value & ".docx"                  'Dateiname =                 Name, Vorname.doc 
                End With 
                .Execute Pause:=False 

                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=Dateiname                   '
                ActiveDocument.Close False 
            End If 

        If .DataSource.ActiveRecord < LetzterRec Then 
             .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord 
          Else 
             Exit Do 
          End If 
       Loop 


    End With 


    MsgBox ("Erledigt") 
    Application.Visible = True 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

    End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=Dateiname, FileFormat:=wdsaveformat.wdFormatPDF

or maybe

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=Dateiname, FileFormat:=wdsaveformat.wdFormatPDF

But it can only work in Word 2007 SP2 (I think) and later.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and let you know later (I am not at work until the end of the week :-( )!

Comment: This one works OK here:
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=Dateiname, FileFormat:=wdsaveformat.wdFormatPDF
But as I said, it won't work on earlier versions of Word 2007 - the PDF format option was not there when it was first released.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2007 it's the export functionality that can save a file as pdf:

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        "Path to PDF", ExportFormat:= _
        wdExportFormatPDF
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit simple, but you can just set your default printer to PDF creator then use the print function.In 2010 you get a print or edit option once you've done the merge.